# Question about iCloud and backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I'm not very familiar with iPhone's iCloud backup mechanism and I have searched online expecting for an answer. Unfortunately, I got into confusion more than finding myself an answer.

## What I have understood so far is;

1. In the phone settings -> under your apple ID -> there's iCloud. Entering in shows how much space I have used and underneath that, says Apps using iCloud (where the **Photos** says `off`). However, when I click the "**manage storage**" under iCloud  shows the storage plan following with `backup`,`secure`,`WhatsApp`,`iCloud Drive`... etc. Further selecting on Backup shows the phone (e.g.: Joe's iPhone) following with `Photo Library`,again `WhatsApp`, `Facebook`.. etc.

Now my question is why is it under Apple ID shows "**APPS USING ICLOUD**" and further drilling down toward "**manage storage**" under **STORAGE** shows another backup?

As I have pointed up on point 1, WhatsApp shows in both places. Does that mean it is backedup twice?

I'm not sure whether I'm making the point right but I'm a bit confused as to how the mechanism is working? whether do I have to necessarily do a complete backup or enable certain require backups such as WhatsApp, Photos/Videos, Viber... etc?